# when should I explicitly import type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm taking the type-challenge from https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/master/questions/898-easy-includes/README.md,and I find something interesting and confusing: **Why files in the same directory could use type without import and export ?**
My project is like :

[image: project]

and I define sometype in `template.ts`

```
// template.ts
type Includes<T extends unknown[], K> = T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? K extends First
    ? true
    : Includes<Rest, K>
  : false
```

and in the some directory ,

```
// test-cases.ts
import { Equal, Expect } from '@type-challenges/utils'

type cases = [
  Expect<
    Equal<Includes<['Kars', 'Esidisi', 'Wamuu', 'Santana'], 'Kars'>, true>
  >,
  Expect<
    Equal<Includes<['Kars', 'Esidisi', 'Wamuu', 'Santana'], 'Dio'>, false>
  >,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], 7>, true>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], 4>, false>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[1, 2, 3], 2>, true>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[1, 2, 3], 1>, true>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[{}], { a: 'A' }>, false>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[boolean, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], false>, false>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[true, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], boolean>, false>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[false, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], false>, true>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[{ a: 'A' }], { readonly a: 'A' }>, false>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[{ readonly a: 'A' }], { a: 'A' }>, false>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[1], 1 | 2>, false>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[1 | 2], 1>, false>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[null], undefined>, false>>,
  Expect<Equal<Includes<[undefined], null>, false>>
]
```

you can see that I didn't export type `Includes` and neither import it , In `test-cases.ts` file I could use it .
but if change the `template.ts` with importing some util type from other directory:

```
// template.ts
import { Equal } from '@type-challenges/utils'

type Includes<T extends unknown[], K> = T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? Equal<First, K> extends true
    ? true
    : Includes<Rest, K>
  : false
```

**I got error in test-cases.ts**,it says  `can't find the name Includes`

could someone explain why is that?

Comment: It is because without `import` or `export` TypeScript believes it is in an ambient context, meaning it is available everywhere in your project. Adding the `import` makes it a module which disables this behaviour

Comment: @kellys thanks , but when I search **ambient context** in the offical docs, it seems that I didn't get what I want. could you give me some links about the mechanism you mentioned? is it about modules? modules is barely like **export** or **import** for me, I just don't know which part defines the "behaviour" ?